# Decryption without client discovering key

Tags: javascript, encryption

Can anyone think of a method which would allow for client-side decryption of a publicly available file without the client being able to determine the decryption key? Of course, if the key was in a JavaScript variable then it would be readily available to the user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve the DRM problem. In short:

1. You have content that is enrypted.
2. An untrusted client wishes to access the content
3. In turn, the client requires the key it was encrypted with.

All systems pretty much boil down to this problem. It is not secure. At best, you can try to hide the key (obfuscation, custom hardware, etc), but that is not a cryptography problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hard truth. Well put.